# I have an issue clicking or tapping an item using Appium-Eclipse-TestNG framework in android emulator

Tags: java, android, appium

New to Appium any help is appreciated

**My code:**

```
public void testmethod() {
    List<MobileElement> buttonlist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.app.Dialog//android.view.View//android.widget.Button"));
    buttonlist.forEach(webElement -> log.info(webElement.getAttribute("name")));
    for (MobileElement button : buttonlist) {
        System.out.println(".................button name=>" + button.getAttribute("name") + "<");
        if ("Send Email ".equals(button.getAttribute("name"))) {
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            button.click();
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

C# for loop prints all the items in the list whereas using java it prints only one. Am I doing something wrong? I see it quickly clicks on top of android screen and closes without clicking the actual element.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the unique element ID to access button. You can access the element using **id**, **resource-id**, **accessibility id** and **xpath**.

> xpath is not recommended

If you don't have unique id in your app elements, you can ask your developer to put it in their code.

You can use **Appium Desktop Inspector** to inspect the element. After knowing the exact element, you can click the button as follow:

```
MobileElement button= driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("your element's accessibility id");
button.click();
//or
MobileElement button= driver.findElementById("your element's id or resource id");
button.click();
```

> You can get or id, resource-id or accessibility-id from appium desktop inspector

If you want to use xpath for your button, get it from the appium desktop inspector and use it as:

```
MobileElement button= driver.findElement(By.xpath("your element's xpath shown in appium"));
button.click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, will give a try

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues I can see in your code.

First, you don't need to call implicit wait in the for loop. Use it once right after initializing driver with time out of 1 min or more.

Second, you have added **extra space** in your if condition, it should be as,

```
if ("Send Email".contains (button.getAttribute("name"))) {
  button.click();
  break;
}
```

Third, is more of a suggestion. Instead of `click`, use `AndroidTouchAction` classes `tap` method like,

```
AndroidTouchAction touch = new AndroidTouchAction (driver);
touch.tap (TapOptions.tapOptions ()
  .withElement (ElementOption.element (e)))
  .perform ();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The names have extra space in it. Also, I tried using trim and equalsIgnoreCase which did not work either. Since it doesn't has any id's nothing has worked including accessibilityId which is //android.widget.Button[@content-desc="Send Email "]

Comment: I have earlier tried touch actions which doesn't work too. 
The tap method throws compilation errors, can you please correct it?

Comment: If tap is throwing compilation error that means you are using old Appium Java client which you need to upgrade to 6.1.0 and use Java jdk 1.8. Once this is done then you won't get compilation errors.